# Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices. error with Django Form

Tags: python, django

I've got a comment section html page and whenever I try to fill the fields and click sumbit it gives the following error - `Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.`

## views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login')
def add_comment(request, slug):
    movie = Movie.objects.get(slug=slug)
    form = CommentForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('movie:movie_list')

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'add_comment.html', context)
```

## forms.py

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('commenter_name', 'comment_body')
        widgets = {
            'commenter_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'comment_body': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

## models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, related_name="comments", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    commenter_name = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment_body = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.movie.title, self.commenter_name)
```

Please note I am able to add a comment through the /admin panel but once I tried adding an API to it things kinda went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've deleted `widgets` from form.py which gave me the following error.
Afterwards I've encountered another error - `NOT NULL constraint failed: movie_comment.post_id`, after changing `views.py` I was able to post successfully

```
@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def comment_create(request, slug):
    movie = Movie.objects.get(slug=slug)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.CommentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid:
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = movie
            comment.author = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('movies:movie_detail', slug=slug)
    else:
        form = forms.CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'add_comment.html', {'form': form})
```

It now works.